# can't create my @current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in ruby on rails, somebody help me?

I can't see @current_user.username

*This is my session_controller

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
    if user
      login user
      redirect_to user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def sucess
  end
  def error
  end   
end
```

*Sessionhelper

```
module SessionHelper
  def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

*controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionHelper
end
```

*My model user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :pass, :username
  validates :username, :pass, :presence => true
  validates :username, :pass, :length => { :minimum => 4 }
  validates :username, :uniqueness => true
```

*application layout

```
  <title>Sessions</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<% if @current_user %>
    Hello <%= @current_user.username %>
    <% end %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
```

*and my login view

```
 <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>   
              <%= f.label :username %>
              <%= f.text_field :username %>

              <%= f.label :pass %>
              <%= f.password_field :pass %>

              <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
    <% end %>
```

please help me :)

Comment: which is the error you see?

Comment: @mayone so what is your question?

Comment: in application layout, i can't see @current_user.username, i just can see it if i create "@current_user = User.find(params[:id])" in session_controller, method sucess.

Comment: @mayone: Update this info in your question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Imo you would rather call current_user, not @current_user in your view. Your views have access to your ApplicationController methods, but not to random instance variables that are not even explicitly set in their controller action. Just try calling current_user in your view and check if that works for you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the method in helper:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

so in templates you should use `current_user` rather then `@current_user`

so, it should be:

```
<body>
    <% if current_user %>
        Hello <%= current_user.username %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>

</body>
```

**UPDATE:**

but it's better to create method in `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

because in this case `current_user` can be called from controllers and templates as well.

Comment: God dammit Marko, just told him the same thing. Have an upvote.

Comment: It work!!!Thank you! Thank you so much, Marko!!! I'm vietnamese and  i just learn ruby on rail for 5 days, i'm very slow in this. Sorry, if my english so bad :)